# Laravel in a subfolder on nginx server

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am trying to set up laravel in a subfolder (`laravel-project`) of a project.
I somehow got the home page to work doing this in the config file:
`rewrite "/project/home.php" /laravel-project/public/index.php$1;`

However I cannot figure out how to get the routing work.
I would like that any request containing `laravel-project` would be redirected to `laravel-project/public/index.php` so that laravel can figure out which controller and which method are to be called.
I did this:

```
location /laravel-project {
  root /home/www/virtual/mysite/laravel-project/public;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

However, when I try to navigate to `mysite/laravel-project` or `mysite/laravel-project/contacts` the application never hits `public/index.php` file in the laravel-project folder.

Hope the information given is enough. Please let me know if any further info is required, and thank you for helping!

Comment: Check this out. https://laravel-news.com/subfolder-install. Essentially, you want to make sure that all of the non-public folders and files are **not** in a public path. This will ensure that users can't browse to sensitive files, especially your `.env`. Then you'll have to change the location for bootstrapping the app. The article explains all of this.

Comment: Thank you but I think I am at a an even earlier stage of the set up. I can't get Laravel to work at all, beside the home page, (with a hard redirect) so, I am still stuck there.

Answer (score 2):

I want to put some new updated tips, maybe it's helps somebody :

If you want to put your `laravel` project in a `subfolder` on a server with `ngnix-ubuntu 16-php.7.2`, so here is update ngnix config :

1) your nested(subfolder) isn't inside your main folder

```
/var/www/main:
/var/www/nested:
```

then your config :

```
location /nested {

        alias /var/www/nested/public;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

               location ~ \.php$ {
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                                }
   }

location @nested {
        rewrite /nested/(.*)$ /nested/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

2) your laravel-test folder (subfolder) inside your main :

```
/var/www/main:
/var/www/main/nested:
```

then your config :

```
location /laravel-test {

    alias /var/www/main/laravel-test/public;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @laravelTest;

           location ~ \.php$ {
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                            }


  }

location @laravelTest {
        rewrite /laravel-test/(.*)$ /laravel-test/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a proper configuration for deploy laravel in sub-folder

```
location /websocket {
    alias /var/www/html/websocket/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @websocket;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                  
    }  
}

location @websocket {
    rewrite /websocket/(.*)$ /websocket/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# megadealer
    location ^~ /megadealer {  
        alias /var/www/choppies/megadealer/public;  
        try_files $uri $uri/ @megadealer;  

        location ~ \.php {  
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/choppies/megadealer/public/index.php;
        }  
    }  

    location @megadealer {
        rewrite /megadealer/(.*)$ /megadealer/index.php?/$1 last;  
    }
    # end megadealer
```